# How to choose RandomAccessFile dynamically?

Tags: java, file, arguments

I had written a program using `RandomAccessFile` class to read binary data.  The code is as follows

```
RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile('BOT.GRD', "r");
in.read(a);
```

Now I want to choose file dynamically rather than providing directly as above. I tried a lot and I was unable to do that. Can any one help me on this?

Comment: What did you try? What do you mean specifically by "dynamically"?

Comment: will help if you can provide more information. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Heh, I thought you meant get a random file to read.

Answer (score 1):

Offer the user a [`JFileChooser`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) to select the `File`.  See [How to Use File Choosers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)
 for more details & examples.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the filename to a variable and pass that into the RandomAccessFile constructor:

```
String filename = "somedynamicname.grd";
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAcessFile(filename, "r");
file.read(a);
```